# AWS EC2 Instance Open Ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rust, port

I was trying to determine why I can always access my AWS EC2 Instance on certain ports, such as port 80.

```
Port range  Protocol    Source            Security groups
22           TCP    98.162.129.68/32    My AWS EC2 SSH Access
22           TCP    107.77.234.218/32   My AWS EC2 SSH Access
```

These are my only rules as of right now - but I can seemingly always access port 80 via a programmatic connection.

Are there default ports that are there that I can turn off somewhere else?

For example:

```
if let Ok(stream) = TcpStream::connect("3.85.107.207:80") {
    println!("Connected to the server!");
    //println!("{}", stream.peer_addr().unwrap());
        Some(stream)
    } else {
        println!("Couldn't connect to server...");
        None
}
```

Comment: can you manually use `telnet 3.85.107.207 80` and see if this works. If so then there is definitely something else going on, otherwise, you need to inspect your code.

Comment: I mean the moment I change it to a different port - it doesn't work - let me check telnet.

Comment: Hrm Telnet doesn't seem to work

Comment: then no other ports are open as you posted the security group configuration, it is working and there are no other ports open. So it goes back to your code.

Comment: Hrmmmmmm - but let's say I do port 81 -my code breaks

Comment: I didnt not get your last comment, but I would check the security group if I am allowing a range there or specific service under `Type` like `ssh`  in security group. Check if there are other `security groups` are attached to the instance. double check if the IP of the instance is  same as I am connecting to.

Comment: The ones I linked are specific to the EC2 Instance I am running - not a specific group - that is why the it specifies the Security Group attached to the port range. Additionally, it seems to be just port 80. Any other port, even 443, doens't work.

Comment: I too can connect to the mentioned ip with the port `Connection to 3.85.107.207 port 80 [tcp/http] succeeded!`.  You need to inspect the security groups, whichever are connected to your instances via aws console. Security groups are the only gatekeeper to allow connections to your instance in the current scenario.

Comment: I have been modifying them. I have turned it off. Can you try now?

Comment: `nc: connectx to 3.85.107.207 port 80 (tcp) failed: Connection refused` it is still open, just that service listening on port `80` is down.

Comment: Okay, that may be my misconception there... how do you know it is still open and that the service is down? Because of the refuse? Is there a way to create a reject rule so it doesn't show that it is connected at all?

Comment: Additionally - I need both 1) the port open via security group and 2) A service listening on a specific port -- for the entirety of a connection to take place, correct?

Comment: I ask because earlier I did **NOT** have the service running and I was still somehow able to get the connection, i.e. the reason I posted this question. I thought I needed a service to listen - and somehow I was still getting a connection via Rust even without it. It seems to be going back to the normal behavior of **BOTH** items required to make a connection

Comment: [Connection Refused means nothing is listening on the IP:Port you are trying to connect to.](https://serverfault.com/a/725263/217508). You dont have to open the port to the whole world, unless needed. You can restrict this to your IP as you have done for `ssh`

Comment: I do need to open it to the whole world - my problem is that the service wasn't listening on a port - but I was still somehow getting a connection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230170/discussion-between-samtoddler-and-impression7vx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments, this issue got resolved by resetting the instance which recycled the instance's public IP. Seems like some trouble where IP was accepting connections even when there was nothing listening on the machine.